# discord.js rateLimitPerUser is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a normal discord bot and I wanna set the slowmode here's my **full** code:

```
bot.on("message", message => {

if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix+"slowmode")) {
  var str = message.content.split(prefix+"slowmode ");
  var num = parseInt(str[1],10);
  message.channel.rateLimitPerUser == rts;
  message.channel.send("Slowmode Setted");
}
```

});

but I get a error :

```
TypeError: message.channel.rateLimitPerUser is not a function
```

I also tried other ways like :

```
message.channel.rateLimitPerUser = num;
```

but they didn't work too. I searched the documentary and internet to set the slowmode but they didn't work too. [ sorry form my bad english :( ]

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code? - is `message.channel` undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use [`.setRateLimitPerUser`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=setRateLimitPerUser)

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'slowmode')) {
    var str = message.content.split(prefix + 'slowmode ');
    var num = parseInt(str[1], 10);
    message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser(num).then(() => {
        message.channel.send(`Slowmode Setted to ${num}s. :thumbsup:`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
        let modchannel = db.fetch(`verify_${message.guild.id}`);
                var sChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(modchannel)
            if (!sChannel) return
    message.sChannel.setRateLimitPerUser(5);
});
```